# using gscam with janus-gateway

Tags: gscam, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When running my pipeline with gst-launch-1.0 in terminal, I get exactly what I want to see. However, when transferring that pipeline to my gscam launchfile, no video stream is recognized on the port. Am I doing something wrong?

my launch file is just a copy of their sample with gscam_config changed:

```
 <launch>

    <arg name="DEVICE" default="/dev/video0"/>
    <arg name="PUBLISH_FRAME" default="false"/>
    <arg name="GST10" default="true"/>

    <node ns="v4l" name="gscam_driver_v4l" pkg="gscam" type="gscam" output="screen">
      <param name="camera_name" value="default"/>
      <param name="camera_info_url" value="package://gscam/examples/uncalibrated_parameters.ini"/>
      <param name="gscam_config" value="v4l2src device=$(arg DEVICE) ! video/x-raw, width=640, height=480 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! x264enc speed-preset=ultrafast tune=zerolatency byte-stream=true bitrate=3000 threads=1 ! h264parse config-interval=1 ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=8004"/>
      <param name="frame_id" value="/v4l_frame"/>
      <param name="sync_sink" value="true"/>
    </node>

    <node if="$(arg PUBLISH_FRAME)" name="v4l_transform" pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" args="1 2 3 0 -3.141 0 /world /v4l_frame 10"/>
</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248852/using-gscam-with-janus-gateway/) by [AlgoRhythm](https://answers.ros.org/users/28626/algorhythm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-11-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> When running my pipeline with gst-launch-1.0 in terminal, I get exactly what I want to see.

'see': where? When you open the rtp stream at `127.0.0.1:8004` in something like VLC?

> However, when transferring that pipeline to my gscam launchfile, no video stream is recognized on the port.

Which 'port'? Would that be `127.0.0.1:8004` again?

According to the `gscam` docs:

> `gscam` can attach itself to a specially formatted pipeline. Provided this pipeline is processing RGB video, `gscam` will rebroadcast the video over as *both* a standard ROS image transport *and* a ROS Camera.

Could it be that the `udpsink` you have in your `gscam_config` is depriving `gscam` from its input, which will make it not publish anything?

Based on the same sentence in the documentation, I assume the `! x264enc speed-preset=ultrafast tune=zerolatency byte-stream=true bitrate=3000 threads=1 ! h264parse config-interval=1 ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=8004` part of your pipeline shouldn't be necessary (there is no infrastructure in ROS to deal with `h264` encoded images or streams).

The purpose of `gscam` is to make it possible to publish RGB output of an arbitrary GStreamer pipeline to a ROS node graph. I'm not sure that is what you had in mind.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AlgoRhythm](https://answers.ros.org/users/28626/algorhythm/) on 2016-11-26**:
the rtp stream in port 8004 should be detected by Janus-gateway and broadcasted over webRTC.
And yes 8004 again.
Yeah I really didnt have a very strong understanding of gscam. Need to take advantage of both the RGB output for image processing, but also want to broadcast a low latency video stream.

**Comment by [AlgoRhythm](https://answers.ros.org/users/28626/algorhythm/) on 2016-11-26**:
Just figured it out! Thanks for your interpretation of the docs @gvdhoorn. Really helped me think though this. For those interested: used tee's in my pipeline. gscam needs `image/jpeg` or `video/x-raw` in RGB to function properly so you have to send over udp in a separate branch.

**Comment by [AlgoRhythm](https://answers.ros.org/users/28626/algorhythm/) on 2016-11-26**:
example:

```
v4l2src device=$(arg DEVICE) ! video/x-raw,width=1280,height=720 ! tee name=t t. ! queue ! x264enc ! h264parse config-interval=1 ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=8004 t. ! queue ! videoconvert
```